# How do I install Webpacker on Heroku with Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, webpacker

I am trying to install a Rails 6 app to Heroku with Webpacker

The git push heroku command seems to trigger the whole build proces

The node.js is invoked successfully and completes.

devDependencies then get pruned apparently.

Then the ruby buildpack kicks in which installs all of the ruby gems and  "detects rake tasks" during which it runs rake assets:precompile

Then I get:

```
Compilation failed:
CLI for webpack must be installed.
webpack-cli (https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli)
```

I am pretty sure I need to run

```
bin/rails webpacker:install
```

somewhere before asset compilation starts, but there is no chance to customise the build script as there is with node.js package.json script hooks for prebuild and postbuild from what I can see and I just end up with:

```
Precompiling assets failed.
Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
```

So how am I supposed to get around this and get webpacker installed properly before heroku tries to compile the assets?

Comment: Did you add `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` as a config var? If not, that's probably why it's failing.

Comment: Thanks for drawing attention to RAILS_MASTER_KEY @sam. This is valuable information as I will definitely need this when I get that far!

Unfortunately at the moment I cant even get the git push to succeed due to the issues I described in my original post - I cant find a point in the ruby buildpack cycle to successfully install webpacker. Any ideas?

Comment: What versions of webpack/webpack-cli are you running? I had an issue (same error) a few weeks ago after bumping my packages to the latest. I ended up downgrading to get everything to work. Sorry, I can't remember exactly what the deal was, but I can try and recreate it.

Comment: The git push kicks of the node.js and then ruby buildpacks.
In my local environment I had to actually explicitly install webpacker with bin/rails webpacker:install even though I have webpacker (5.2.1) in my Gemfile.
In heroku the rake assets:precompile task kicks off automatically but hits:
Compilation failed:
CLI for webpack must be installed.
webpack-cli (https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli)
We will use "yarn" to install the CLI via "yarn add -D webpack-cli".
Do you want to install 'webpack-cli' (yes/no): 
Precompiling assets failed.
Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.

Comment: Of course the above runs in a script and so I never get a chance to answer "yes" to installing webpack-cli.
I'm so confused.
Anyway thanks for your assistance @rmlockerd

Comment: I should also mention that my package.json contains the lines:

  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-cli": "^4.3.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.1"
  },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution is that because I am running 2 buildpacks in sequence, node.js followed by ruby, I need to prevent the node.js buildpack from pruning the devdependencies (ie webpack) defined in package.json as:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-cli": "^4.3.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.1"
  },
```

by:

```
echo Setting Heroku to not prune dev dependencies
heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false YARN_PRODUCTION=false
```

The net result is I think that when the ruby buildpack comes to call the assets:precompile rake task that the webpacker CLI is still installed whereas previously it was not.